# Movimentar imagens em VB6

Tags: visual-basic-6, vba, microsoft-access

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command0_Click()
    Do Until Me.Width < 4000
        Let Image1.Left = Image1.Left - 5
    DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

Assim como esta permite mover a imagem do lado direito para esquerdo como fazer para a imagem rodar todo o fomulário,Sem parar com um botão e sem usar o timer? Alguém tem uma ideia eficaz de como fazer isso?

Comment: Poderia nos dizer por que não dá certo?

Comment: oy Cigano eu quero na vedrdade que a imagem circule em todos os cantos do formulario( a imagem deve dar a volta sobre o formulario sem o timer de preferencia em Excel.vba ou vb6). é possivel criar um ciclo capaz de fazer isto tenho um teste relacionado com isto agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: imagine que tenhas uma bola inicialmente a bola esta no canto inferior esquerdo mas tens que mover pra  cima depois pra o lado direito,depois pra baixo voltar pra o lado esquerdo(como se estivese a dar uma volta na casa e voltar para a posicao inicial )como ficaria isto usando um select,for,while, ou outra instrutura de laço.Access ou Excel.vba

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro eu abandonaria sua variável `Indo`. No caso, usaria um `Enum`:

```vb
Enum Movimento
    Cima
    Baixo
    Esquerda
    Direita
End Enum
```

E declararia uma variável chamada `mov`:

```vb
Dim mov as Movimento
```

Neste caso, a `Sub` teria que ter, ao invés de um `If`, um `Select Case`:

```vb
Select Case mov
    Case Movimento.Cima
        Picture1.Left = Picture1.Top - 10

        'Se bateu em cima, vai pra esquerda
        If Picture1.Top >= ScaleHeight - Picture1.Height Then
            mov = Movimento.Esquerda
            Picture1.Top = ScaleHeight - Picture1.Height
            Exit Do
        End If
    Case Movimento.Baixo
        Picture1.Left = Picture1.Top + 10

        'Se bateu em cima, vai pra esquerda
        If Picture1.Top >= ScaleHeight - Picture1.Height Then
            mov = Movimento.Direita
            Picture1.Top = ScaleHeight - Picture1.Height
            Exit Do
        End If
    Case Movimento.Esquerda
        Picture1.Left = Picture1.Left + 10

       'Se bateu no lado direito, vai pra baixo
       If Picture1.Left >= ScaleWidth - Picture1.Width Then
            mov = Movimento.Baixo
            Picture1.Left = ScaleWidth - Picture1.Width
            Exit Do
        End If
    Case Else ' Ou seja, Movimento.Direita
        Picture1.Left = Picture1.Left - 10

        'Se bateu no lado esquero, sobe.
        If Picture1.Left <= 0 Then
            mov = Movimento.Cima
            Picture1.Left = 0
            Exit Do
        End If
     End Select
```

Este código com certeza vai precisar de algum ajuste, mas tem a ideia geral.

Comment: tentei ajustar este mas nao deu certo ainda nao core

Answer (score 0):

Para aquilo que eu queria isto ficaria assim:

```
Option Compare Database
Dim i As Integer
Private Sub Command1_Click()

For i = 1 To 900
Me.Width = 1000
Let Image3.left = Image3.left - 5
DoEvents
Next
For i = 900 To 1200
Me.Width = 1000
Let Image3.top = Image3.top + 5
DoEvents
Next
For i = 1800 To 2700
Me.Width = 1000
Let Image3.left = Image3.left + 5
DoEvents
Next
For i = 2700 To 3000
Me.Width = 1000
Let Image3.top = Image3.top - 5
DoEvents
Next
End Sub
```